# PHP: How to retrieve values of multiple form inputs with the same name,?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox, and next to each checkbox I have a select option. I have multiple of these, and I want to retrieve the value of the select only if the checkbox is checked for it.

Here is the code:

```
<form method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1[]">
    <select name="select1[]">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select
```

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1[]">
    <select name="select1[]">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="go">
</form>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_POST['check1']); $i++){
        if(isset($_POST['check1'][$i])){
            echo $_POST['select1'][$i];
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work, if the first checkbox is unchecked then the for loop returns the value of the second select option. Otherwise it works fine. How can i fix this?

Here is the array:

```
[check1] => Array
    (
        [0] => on
        [1] => on
    )

[select1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
    )
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you're not using unique names?

Comment: @enhzflep i have an unknown number of these.

Comment: in your php code try to put this line then you will what you are getting on your php page... echo '<pre>';print_r($_REQUEST );echo '</pre>';

Comment: @Zeeshan cant understand your code, can you make it more clear pls.

Comment: @user3898380 on your PHP code file add this line: **echo '<pre>';print_r($_REQUEST );echo '</pre>';**

Comment: @Zeeshan Ok, that prints the array. But how can i fix this?

Comment: can you update your question with that array and what you want from that array ?

Comment: @Zeeshan Done. my php code above works fine, but if the first checkbox is unchecked then the value of select1 is 1, when it should be 3. Do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

We get only checked check box on server that was your for loop is false over there.

In this code i have add value to each check box to identify select box.

eq: if check1[0] == 0 then we get select1[0]

```
if check1[1] == 1 then we get select1[1]
```

Sorry for my english.

Html code

```
<form action='' method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value='0'>
        <select name="select1[]">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1[]" value='1'>
        <select name="select1[]">
            <option value="4">One</option>
            <option value="5">Two</option>
            <option value="6">Three</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="go">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['check1'])){
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['check1']);$i++){
        if($_POST['check1'][$i] >= 0){
            echo $_POST['select1'][$_POST['check1'][$i]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do otherwise. When the checkbox is checked, in javascript I would activate the select input and retrieve eventually the result in a hidden field. You could also change the value of the checked input to 1 only when it is activated and **link it to an hidden input field.**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1[]">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenValue[]" value="0">
    <select name="select1[]">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select
```

You have to understand that only checked input are send to the server so your array for check1[] will be different from the one you expected. If you want to be sure. Index your arrays ; This may help your php loop :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1[0]">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1[1]">
```

By the way my select input would begin with an empty option and no checkbox. checking the empty value for an option is easier. But may be you need this checkbox so it was just an info.

```
<select name="select1[]">
        <option value="0">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="4">One</option>
        <option value="5">Two</option>
        <option value="6">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think iterating over the check1 array from end to start would solve this?

Comment: not sure but you have to understand if the first check1[] is not checked then your array wont be ordered like you think. that's why based on your approach i would add an hidden field and my loop would use the hidden field. so I would add a little bit of javascript. Or switch to a radio button.